# how to set the alpha theme version in my new blender 2.8 version thanks

Tags: interface, theme

i download the new version blender 2.8, but i need to change the interface or theme in my new blender 2.8. isit possible?[image]

Comment: "*is it possible?*" No, that is not a different theme

Comment: Blender 2.8 is in development, it's changing from one day to another. So you have to be ready to follow the changes. If you're not ready for that, wait for the actual release.

Comment: Have you tried User Preferences, experimentally? I am not making suggestions, but I wonder if User Preferences allow anyone UI choices. Can user keep the old looks of 2.79 interface inside 2.8?